# Are there languages which support concatenative inheritance from multiple prototypes?

Tags: javascript, multiple-inheritance, prototype-programming

So that both prototypes and their descendants live their own independent lives by default.

I mean freely taking on new properties while forgetting where they come from (like with human memory -- often we know something without remembering where that knowledge comes from).
Trying to find a natural form of conceptual model that works similar to our own development.
If I am not mistaken, JavaScript, for example, would always trace where new properties come from.

Comment: This "_So that both prototypes and their descendants live their own independent lives by default._" does not describe inheritance - it describes encapsulation. Just like human memory, the things we know are encapsulated in our memory bank - but we didn't _inherit_ that knowledge from parents - it was added to our memory where it was encapsulated. But, this is not the forum for such a question. I suppose this will be closed very quickly.

Comment: JS object doesn't "trace" its properties, it's not aware where else they're used, and properties are not aware in which object they're defined.

Comment: Sounds related to [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [concatenative inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming#Concatenation) you are talking about is defined by not remembering the prototype, but just copying over the properties. This means no prototype chain, and no dynamic dispatch.

[JavaScript supports this trivially](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/the-heart-soul-of-prototypal-oo-concatenative-inheritance-a3b64cb27819) (e.g. using `Object.assign` or spread syntax in an object literal, with multiple sources), as do some other languages.